boost::program_options in window conda environment throws "Bad Allocation"
I'm trying to compile an appliation, in Windows, in Conda, with VS2019.
My CMakeLists.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MyProject)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(my_program po_demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_program Boost::program_options)


My example application:
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    try {
        po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("help", "produce help message")
            ("input-file", po::value<std::string>(), "set input file")
            ("output-file", po::value<std::string>(), "set output file")
            ("verbose,v", "enable verbose output")
            ("optimization-level", po::value<int>()->default_value(0), "set optimization level")
        ;

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            std::cout << "Usage: program_name [options]\n";
            std::cout << desc;
            return 0;
        }

    } catch (const po::error& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } catch (std::exception ex) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Error unknown" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

I create an environment (from a miniforge3 prompt):
conda create -n potest
conda activate potest
conda install cxx-compiler libboost-devel cmake make

mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=%CONDA_PREFIX% -G "Unix Makefiles" ..

make

Program output:
Error: bad allocation

CMake reports that it finds the boost library in the environment.   dumpbin reports the following:
Dump of file my_program.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Image has the following dependencies:

    boost_program_options.dll
    MSVCP140D.dll
    VCRUNTIME140D.dll
    VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll
    ucrtbased.dll
    KERNEL32.dll

  Summary

        1000 .00cfg
        2000 .data
        4000 .idata
        3000 .pdata
        B000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       1F000 .text
        1000 .tls

The issue occurs on the very first line of the application.  If I change from po::options_description desc("Allowed options"); to po::options_description desc; then we will instead continue until po::notify and the error will instead be: Error: vector too long.  Additionally it will pop up this dialog:

I'm pretty confused.  Should this work?  Is there a compatibility issue between the conda versions of boost and this compiler?

It looks like you are compiling your program in debug mode and linking against a release build of boost. Use the debug build instead. It might be called boost_program_optionsd.dll by convention, but who knows with conda.

Thank you!  Adding -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release made it work.
I thought that cmake would have automatically used the debug libraries.  Is this a windows specific thing?  I switch between debug and release on Linux quite frequently.

So it turns out that the conda package for boost doesn't ship with the debug versions.  I would have liked if CMake would've complained about that.

Good find! Suggest you post that as a self-answer so others can find it.

The conda's boost library in windows doesn't include the debug versions.  See here.
I was attempting to build with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug which then caused a mix of debug and non-debug libraries.  I wasn't aware that this was a problem as it appears to be a minor issue in Linux.  But in windows it appears to be a very big issue.
Thank you Botje for the information.
